# How to sum up a joined table in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

What should I do if I want to sum the headcount column from a joined table?

I tried using this query:

```
SELECT A.Job, A.Site, count(B.Job) HeadCount FROM tble_1 A LEFT join tble_2 B ON A.Job = B.Job AND A.Site = B.Site GROUP BY A.Job

RESULT:
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| Jobs           | Site           | Headcount      |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Doctor   |             US |             10 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Artist   |         Mexico |             10 | 
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Doctor   |          Japan |             10 | 
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Doctor   |        Germany |             10 | 
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Doctor   |         Russia |             10 | 
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Actor    |          India |             10 | 
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

How can I achieve this result:

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| Jobs           | Site           | Headcount      | Total          |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Doctor   |             US |             10 |             30 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Artist   |         Mexico |             10 |             10 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Doctor   |          Japan |             10 |             30 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Doctor   |        Germany |             10 |             30 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Actor    |         Russia |             10 |             20 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       Actor    |          India |             10 |             20 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Note: The total column is the sum of headcount.

Comment: Just to make sure, it's the sum of *all* rows headcounts for that job regardless of country?

Comment: And what version of sqlite are you using? This should be trivial with a window function, but that needs 3.25 or newer.

Comment: Wait, you're only grouping on job, not job and country? How are you getting that example output then? And where did Russia's Actor come from in the second one?

Comment: I'm using the latest version, yes i just want the to sum the regardless of any country.

Answer (score 0):

use scalar subquery

```
SELECT A.Job, A.Site, count(B.Job) HeadCount,
(select count(*) FROM tble_1 A1 where A.job=A1.job) as total
FROM tble_1 A LEFT join tble_2 B ON A.Job = B.Job AND A.Site = B.Site 
GROUP BY A.Job
```

Comment: Yay, that works now. But consider the case where table 1 has a row without any matches in table 2 (Like the samples in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can try using two separate subqueries for each count:

```
SELECT
    t1.Job,
    t1.Site,
    COALESCE(t3.HeadCount, 0) AS HeadCount,
    COALESCE(t2.SiteCount, 0) AS Total
FROM tble_1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Job, COUNT(*) AS SiteCount
    FROM tble_1 
    GROUP BY Job
) t2
    ON t1.Job = t2.Job
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT A.Job, A.Site, COUNT(*) AS HeadCount
    FROM tble_1 A
    LEFT JOIN tble_2 B
        ON A.Job = B.Job AND A.Site = B.Site
    GROUP BY A.Job, A.Site
) t3
    ON t1.Job = t3.Job AND t1.Site = t3.Site;
```

### Demo

(demo data kindly provided by @Shawn)

Comment: I don't think, based on what OP appears to be trying to do, that produces the right results when there's a row in table 1 that doesn't have a corresponding row in table 2. Try it on the sample tables in my answer and look at the difference in the Actor results.

Comment: @Shawn Have a look at my demo link and tell me where you think my query is going wrong.

Comment: Changing `COUNT(*) AS HeadCount` to `COUNT(B.Job) AS HeadCount` to match OP gives 0 for `(Actor, Mexico)`, but still has the wrong total, which is supposed to be the sum of headcount values.

Comment: (All of this might be moot if OP's data doesn't involve such a case, of course. I threw it in for the sake of completeness)

Answer (score 0):

Your sample output can't possibly have come from the query in your post (You only group on one column and the results are based on grouping on two columns; there should only be one row per job as your query stands), and there's no sample data to test with, so fixing that up, I think this'll do what you want (Requires Sqlite 3.25 or newer):

```
SELECT a.job AS Job
     , a.site AS Site
     , count(b.job) AS Headcount
     , sum(count(b.job)) OVER (PARTITION BY a.job) AS Total
FROM tble_1 AS a
LEFT JOIN tble_2 AS b ON a.job = b.job AND a.site = b.site
GROUP BY a.job, a.site;
```

Given the following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tble_1(job text, site text);
INSERT INTO tble_1 VALUES('Doctor','US');
INSERT INTO tble_1 VALUES('Doctor','Japan');
INSERT INTO tble_1 VALUES('Doctor','Germany');
INSERT INTO tble_1 VALUES('Artist','Mexico');
INSERT INTO tble_1 VALUES('Actor','Russia');
INSERT INTO tble_1 VALUES('Actor','India');
INSERT INTO tble_1 VALUES('Actor','Mexico');
CREATE TABLE tble_2(job text, site text);
INSERT INTO tble_2 VALUES('Doctor','US');
INSERT INTO tble_2 VALUES('Doctor','Japan');
INSERT INTO tble_2 VALUES('Doctor','Germany');
INSERT INTO tble_2 VALUES('Artist','Mexico');
INSERT INTO tble_2 VALUES('Actor','Russia');
INSERT INTO tble_2 VALUES('Actor','India');
INSERT INTO tble_2 VALUES('Doctor','Germany');
CREATE INDEX tble_1_idx ON tble_1(job, site);
CREATE INDEX tble_2_idx ON tble_2(job, site);
```

this produces:

```
Job         Site        Headcount   Total     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
Actor       India       1           2         
Actor       Mexico      0           2         
Actor       Russia      1           2         
Artist      Mexico      1           1         
Doctor      Germany     2           4         
Doctor      Japan       1           4         
Doctor      US          1           4
```